# Complete ROS uninstallation?

Tags: ros, package, ros-groovy

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi guys,

Even though i have tried to uninstall ROS using sudo apt-get remove ros-groovy-*, still there are some remaining packages like: ros-groovy-bfl, ros-groovy-opencv2 ... etc.
Did anybody know how to completely remove them because i want to try a fresh installation of ROS and i dont want to have something from the previous installation.

Thank you in advance!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/66194/complete-ros-uninstallation?/) by [Albtech](https://answers.ros.org/users/5273/albtech/) on ROS Answers with karma: 28 on 2013-06-27

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [felix k](https://answers.ros.org/users/606/felix-k/) on 2013-06-29**:
I don't know in which situation it actually matters but most times I use `purge` instead of `remove`, so the package's configuration is cleaned.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Use

```
sudo apt-get purge ros-*
```

It will also remove configuration files. And then

```
sudo apt-get autoremove
```

To remove dependencies

---

Originally posted by [tonyParker](https://answers.ros.org/users/15131/tonyparker/) with karma: 377 on 2014-09-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 8

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [lordricky](https://answers.ros.org/users/29169/lordricky/) on 2017-02-11**:
I would add:
`sudo apt-get purge python-ros*`

before running the autoremove command

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I also used 'sudo apt-get autoremove' which uninstalls unused references as well. You could also remove the remaining packages individually and then performe the autoremove again so that also all unsed dependencies of the packages are removed.

---

Originally posted by [Johannes Mayr](https://answers.ros.org/users/4705/johannes-mayr/) with karma: 81 on 2013-06-28

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Albtech](https://answers.ros.org/users/5273/albtech/) on 2013-06-28**:
Still these packages remained unaffected. Anyway thank you for effort!